# App Engine Datastore IN Operator - how to use?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, google-cloud-datastore

Reading: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

I want to use:

:=  IN

but am unsure how to make it work.  Let's assume the following

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class UniqueListOfSavedItems(db.Model):
    str = db.StringPropery()
    datesaved = db.DateTimeProperty()

class UserListOfSavedItems(db.Model):
    name = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection='user')
    str = db.ReferenceProperty(UniqueListOfSavedItems, collection='itemlist')
```

How can I do a query which gets me the list of saved items for a user?  Obviously I can do:

```
q = db.Gql("SELECT * FROM UserListOfSavedItems WHERE name :=", user[0].name)
```

but that gets me a list of keys.  I want to now take that list and get it into a query to get the str field out of UniqueListOfSavedItems.  I thought I could do:

```
q2 = db.Gql("SELECT * FROM UniqueListOfSavedItems WHERE := str in q")
```

but something's not right...any ideas?  Is it (am at my day job, so can't test this now):

```
q2 = db.Gql("SELECT * FROM UniqueListOfSavedItems __key__ := str in q)
```

side note: what a devilishly difficult problem to search on because all I really care about is the "IN" operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have a list of keys, you don't need to do a second query - you can do a batch fetch, instead. Try this:

```
#and this should get me the items that a user saved
useritems = db.get(saveditemkeys)
```

(Note you don't even need the guard clause - a db.get on 0 entities is short-circuited appropritely.)

What's the difference, you may ask? Well, a db.get takes about 20-40ms. A query, on the other hand (GQL or not) takes about 160-200ms. But wait, it gets worse! The IN operator is implemented in Python, and translates to multiple queries, which are executed serially. So if you do a query with an IN filter for 10 keys, you're doing 10 separate 160ms-ish query operations, for a total of about 1.6 seconds latency. A single db.get, in contrast, will have the same effect and take a total of about 30ms.

Comment: What a great answer...I will implement this tonight.  I got the code working (yeah!) so optimization can come later. :)  Right now I am on regular expressions.  Banging. Head. On. Keyboard.

Comment: Brandon - I use an app called regexbuddy, which helps a lot. Not associated with them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Adam for getting me on the right track.  Based on his pointer, and doing some searching at Code Search, I have the following solution.

```
usersaveditems = User.Gql(“Select * from UserListOfSavedItems where user =:1”, userkey)

saveditemkeys = []

for item in usersaveditems:
    #this should create a list of keys (references) to the saved item table
    saveditemkeys.append(item.str())    

if len(usersavedsearches > 0):
    #and this should get me the items that a user saved
    useritems = db.Gql(“SELECT * FROM UniqueListOfSavedItems WHERE __key__ in :1’, saveditemkeys)
```